# Gradle: gradle install with javadocs

Tags: java, gradle

I'm making use of the Gradle `maven` plugin to build an artefact that is to be used for another unrelated project.  Along with the built *.jar* artefact, I would also like to generate and install the *-javadoc.jar* artefact along side it.

Using `gradle clean build javadoc install` generates the JavaDoc in the local *build* file, and install the built artefact to the local repository, but it currently does not build and install *-javadoc.jar* along side it.

Is there a way to do this in Gradle using the `maven` or `javadoc` plugin?  I don't mind writing a custom task to do it, but I rather use the "officially supported" way if one exists.

The *build.gradle* file:

```
project.group = "org.example.artefact"
project.version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'

dependencies {
    // ...
}

uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            // Custom repository location
            repository(url: "file:///home/user/.m3/repository")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good question... I did get my build.gradle files to do that but I don't understand why they work at all...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Javadocs are produced by the `javadoc` **task** (I think you are mistakenly referring to it as a plugin). This task isn't actually executed by default when running `build` or `install`. Additionally you'll want to define a `jar` task to bundle the javadocs and tell your build to publish that artifact by adding it to the `artifacts {...}` block.

```
task javadocJar(type: Jar) {
    classifier = 'javadoc'
    from javadoc
}   

artifacts {
    archives javadocJar
}
```

Running `install` should then both create the javadoc jar and publish it to maven local. Additionally, running `uploadArchives` would then publish that artifact to any configured repositories.

**Edit:** Updated to add definition of javadoc `jar` task.

Comment: Thanks.  This helped with the solution.  The only thing was that the javadoc task did not produce a Jar artefact (in the version of Gradle I'm using: 2.2.1) so I had to introduce a custom task to produce the javadoc jar.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. I've updated my answer to reflect the need to create an additional `jar` task.

Answer (score 1):

2023 -> Since Gradle 6.0 you can use new `withJavadocJar()` method in java plugin extension. See [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/6.0/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java-extension).

> Automatically packages Javadoc and creates a variant javadocElements with an artifact -javadoc.jar, which will be part of the publication.

This means javadoc.jar artifact will automagically be created alongside your standard jar package with compiled classes and be ready for publishing.

Example:

```
java {
  withJavadocJar()
}
```

More detailed documentation in [Gradle javadoc for JavaPluginExtension](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/plugins/JavaPluginExtension.html#withJavadocJar--).